# Consumer Producer Problem - Is synchronization always necessary?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized, producer-consumer

My question is purely conceptual. And merely for a deeper understanding of communication between threads.

In a Producer Consumer problem,

- There is one producer thread and one consumer thread.
- The producer thread calls the method produce and the Consumer thread calls the method consume.

[The example code is taken from here](https://dzone.com/articles/the-evolution-of-producer-consumer-problem-in-java)

```
package ProducerConsumer;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
public class ClassicProducerConsumerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Buffer buffer = new Buffer(2);
        Thread producerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    buffer.produce();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    buffer.consume();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        producerThread.start();
        consumerThread.start();
        producerThread.join();
        consumerThread.join();
    }
    static class Buffer {
        private Queue<Integer> list;
        private int size;
        public Buffer(int size) {
            this.list = new LinkedList<>();
            this.size = size;
        }
        public void produce() throws InterruptedException {
            int value = 0;
            while (true) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    while (list.size() >= size) {
                        // wait for the consumer
                        wait();
                    }
                    list.add(value);
                    System.out.println("Produced " + value);
                    value++;
                    // notify the consumer
                    notify();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
        public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    while (list.size() == 0) {
                        // wait for the producer
                        wait();
                    }
                    int value = list.poll();
                    System.out.println("Consume " + value);
                    // notify the producer
                    notify();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have read that wait and notify should be inside the synchronized block to avoid race condition.

I don't understand why I should enclose the wait() and notify() in synchronized block when both the threads are calling different methods. Consumer thread is not going to call produce() so if I do not enclose the wait call inside the produce method with synchronized keyword then it should still behave the same because produce() is only being called by the Producer thread. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer which both threads are adding/removing from, is a linked list. Java's linked list is not thread safe.

However, you can abstract out this locking into the data structure itself by using a [concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) version.

---

**Another fallout:** While in this example there is only producer and only one consumer, that may not be the case always. Having more than one producer and/or consumer may have a use case where synchronization is required, even for a thread-safe data structure.

Comment: Does it mean that if producer thread has the lock, the consumer thread cannot alter the list because the list is a variable of the same instance producer and consumer are using?

What i know already is if one thread has the lock the other thread cannot execute that code. Don't know if synchronize can ensure limited access to the shared variable as well. Can you elaborate that point?

Comment: @Sibgha: I think that is not true. Synchronizing means that at a time only one thread can enter *that* method. So, all it means is that there can't be two threads inside produce() or two threads inside consume(). It doesn't mean that producer/consumer cannot access list because another thread is inside a different synchronized method.

Comment: Based on that, the code should work without synchronized because the producer is using a different method to alter the list. The method consume for instance is only for Consumer thread.

Comment: @Sibgha: They are using different methods, but the different methods are modifying the same list. Therefore some locking is needed to ensure that the list is used as intended. In this case, synchronization is being used to perform that locking.